# ¿Se puede decir "dobla en cuanto a sus edades" y "le dobla en edad"?

Tags: gramática

¿"Dobla en cuanto a sus edades ('edades' porque se trata de más de una persona)", "le dobla en edad" y "le dobla la edad" son iguales de significado? - la pregunta viene de esta oración que apareció en una conversación: "La pareja de mi hijo le dobla la edad". Gracias.

Comment: Le acabo de plantear esta pregunta al servicio de consultas de la RAE. Paciencia. :)

Comment: Gracias, Pablo.

Comment: Más correcto sería "La pareja de mi hijo tiene doble su edad."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Le dobla en edad** es correcta y de uso relativamente frecuente. **Le dobla la edad** también es gramaticalmente correcto aunque no lo he visto tan frecuentemente.

La otra construcción "le dobla en cuanto a sus edades" es correcta pero excesivamente recargada y hasta suena antinatural. Sería preferible decir algo como "dobla sus edades" o "tiene el doble de la edad de ellos".

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones.